# Trig Problem Involving Terminal Points, Tangents, and Slopes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Point $A$ is the terminal point of $\phi$ and point $B$ is the terminal point of $\theta$. Point $A$ is in the first quadrant and point $B$ is in the second quadrant, while $\tan \phi = 1$ and $\tan \theta = -7$. Find the slope of $\overline{AB}$.

---

I have no idea how to solve this.  Solutions are very helpful :)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Terminal points on what?  The unit circle?

Answer (score 0):

For unit radius vector ( using 1,2 in place of A,B):

$$ \arctan ( 1) = t1 \quad   \arctan (-7 ) = t2 $$

$$ x1= \cos t1 , y1 = \sin t1,\quad x2 =  \cos t2 , y2 = \sin t2 $$

Find slope AB as:

$$ \frac{ y2-y1}{x2-x1}. $$

EDT1:

Slope AB works out to ( check error in $x2$ sign, red line, not blue)

$$-\frac13$$

[image: Error in Sign]

Comment: I got $3$ as the final answer, is it correct?

Comment: I got the same result.  $$\frac{\sin(\tan^{-1}(-7))-\sin(\tan^{-1}(1))}{\cos(\tan^{-1}(-7))-\cos(\tan^{-1}(1))}=3$$

Comment: Wait, $3$ is not the correct answer, do you know where we could have miscalculated?

Comment: This was a problem I encountered online, and when I typed in $3,$ it said it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Gradient of AB= 8/(1.43+0.79) = 3.61 (see pic)